# How to move each ellipses with different set of keys in processing?

Tags: key, processing, ellipse

I want to add/remove an ellipse using a press of a button in Processing. I use void keyPressed() and void keyReleased() for the keys. 
Now that i can add more , and remove some ellipses. For example, if i have one i can press a button then have one more. Or press a button to remove one. But now I would like to move those ellipses (max 4) using different key sets for each of them. So I made 4 different sets but now I can't make them move at the same time. How can I do that? Please help me. Below is my code.

```
final static int N1= 1;                           //players can move at the same time
final static int S1 = 2;                           
final static int E1 = 4;                           
final static int W1 = 8;                           // Speed limit. Round out edges for field (silhouette)
                                              // if time Collision detection

final static int N2 = 16;
final static int S2 = 32;
final static int E2 = 64;
final static int W2 = 128;


final static int N3 = 256;
final static int S3 = 512;
final static int E3 = 1024;
final static int W3 = 2048;

final static int N4 = 4096;
final static int S4 = 8192;
final static int E4 = 16384;
final static int W4 = 32768;

int result,k;                                  //store key input and initial number of players on field
float x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,n,r;             //Decleare some useful variables


boolean sketchFullScreen() {                        //Make full screen
return true;
}



void setup() {                                      //Basic setup
size(displayWidth, displayHeight);                //Window size maximum
noCursor();                                       //Hide mouse cursor
frameRate(60);                                   //set the frame rate, can lower the rate for lower performent pc
result = 0;
k = 1;
n = 8;                                            //initial movement speed
r = 15;                                           //initial radius of bubble

x1 = 2*width/3;                                    
y1 = height/3; 
x2 = 2*width/3;                                    //light dot initial position
y2 = 2*height/3; 
x3 = width/3;                                  
y3 = height/3; 
x4 = width/3;                                    
y4 = 2*height/3;
}



void draw() {                                        //Start drawing
background(0);                                     //Black background(COMPLETELY BLACK)
switch(result){   
case N1: y1=y1-n; break;
case E1: x1=x1+n; break;
case S1: y1=y1+n; break;
case W1: x1=x1-n; break;                            //create movement to the dot by reassigning the coordinates
case N1|E1: y1=y1-n; x1=x1+n; break;                    
case N1|W1: y1=y1-n; x1=x1-n; break;
case S1|E1: y1=y1+n; x1=x1+n; break;
case S1|W1: y1=y1+n; x1=x1-n; break;

case N2: y2=y2-n; break;
case E2: x2=x2+n; break;
case S2: y2=y2+n; break;
case W2: x2=x2-n; break;                            //create movement to the dot by reassigning the coordinates
case N2|E2: y2=y2-n; x2=x2+n; break;                    
case N2|W2: y2=y2-n; x2=x2-n; break;
case S2|E2: y2=y2+n; x2=x2+n; break;
case S2|W2: y2=y2+n; x2=x2-n; break;

case N3: y3=y3-n; break;
case E3: x3=x3+n; break;
case S3: y3=y3+n; break;
case W3: x3=x3-n; break;                            //create movement to the dot by reassigning the coordinates
case N3|E3: y3=y3-n; x3=x3+n; break;                    
case N3|W3: y3=y3-n; x3=x3-n; break;
case S3|E3: y3=y3+n; x3=x3+n; break;
case S3|W3: y3=y3+n; x3=x3-n; break;

case N4: y4=y4-n; break;
case E4: x4=x4+n; break;
case S4: y4=y4+n; break;
case W4: x4=x4-n; break;                            //create movement to the dot by reassigning the coordinates
case N4|E4: y4=y4-n; x4=x4+n; break;                    
case N4|W4: y4=y4-n; x4=x4-n; break;
case S4|E4: y4=y4+n; x4=x4+n; break;
case S4|W4: y4=y4+n; x4=x4-n; break;
}

if(k>=5){k=4;}                                  //max bumber of players is 4
if(k<0){k=0;}                                   //least amount of players is 0


if(x1<0){x1=r/2;}
else if(x1>displayWidth){x1=displayWidth-r/2;}
if(x2<0){x2=r/2;}
else if(x2>displayWidth){x2=displayWidth-r/2;}
if(x3<0){x3=r/2;}
else if(x3>displayWidth){x3=displayWidth-r/2;}
if(x4<0){x4=r/2;}
else if(x4>displayWidth){x4=displayWidth-r/2;}

if(y1<0){y1=r/2;}
else if(y1>displayHeight){y1=displayHeight-r/2;}
if(y2<0){y2=r/2;}
else if(y2>displayHeight){y2=displayHeight-r/2;}
if(y3<0){y3=r/2;}
else if(y3>displayHeight){y3=displayHeight-r/2;}
if(y4<0){y4=r/2;}
else if(y4>displayHeight){y4=displayHeight-r/2;}


stroke(255);                                        //White light stroke
if(k==1){ellipse(x1,y1,r,r);}                       //Draw an ellipse at location (x,y) xwith radius of 15 pixels
if(k==2){
ellipse(x1,y1,r,r); 
ellipse(x2,y2,r,r);
    }

if(k==3){
ellipse(x1,y1,r,r); 
ellipse(x2,y2,r,r);
ellipse(x3,y3,r,r);
    }

if(k==4){
ellipse(x1,y1,r,r); 
ellipse(x2,y2,r,r);
ellipse(x3,y3,r,r);
ellipse(x4,y4,r,r);
     }
}         


void keyPressed() {
switch(key) {
case('w'):case('W'):result |=N1;break;
case('d'):case('D'):result |=E1;break;
case('s'):case('S'):result |=S1;break;              //classify the cases for the key pressed
case('a'):case('A'):result |=W1;break;}
switch(key) { 
case('8'):result |=N2;break;
case('6'):result |=E2;break;
case('5'):result |=S2;break;              
case('4'):result |=W2;break;}
switch(key) {
case('t'):case('T'):result |=N3;break;
case('h'):case('H'):result |=E3;break;
case('g'):case('G'):result |=S3;break;              
case('f'):case('F'):result |=W3;break;}
switch(key) {
case('i'):case('I'):result |=N4;break;
case('l'):case('L'):result |=E4;break;
case('k'):case('K'):result |=S4;break;              
case('j'):case('J'):result |=W4;break;}
switch(key) {
case('+'):case('='): n++;break;
case('_'):case('-'): n--;break;                    //change movement speed
case('['):case('{'): r=r-1;break;                  //change radius of bubble
case(']'):case('}'): r=r+1;break;
case(':'): k--;break;                            //add and take away players
case('"'): k++;break;
}
}

void keyReleased(){  
switch(key) {                                      
case('w'):case('W'):result ^=N1;break;
case('d'):case('D'):result ^=E1;break;
case('s'):case('S'):result ^=S1;break;              //classify the cases for the key pressed
case('a'):case('A'):result ^=W1;break;}
switch(key) {  
case('8'):result ^=N2;break;
case('6'):result ^=E2;break;
case('5'):result ^=S2;break;              
case('4'):result ^=W2;break;}
switch(key) {
case('t'):case('T'):result ^=N3;break;
case('h'):case('H'):result ^=E3;break;
case('g'):case('G'):result ^=S3;break;              
case('f'):case('F'):result ^=W3;break;}
switch(key) {
case('i'):case('I'):result ^=N4;break;
case('l'):case('L'):result ^=E4;break;
case('k'):case('K'):result ^=S4;break;              
case('j'):case('J'):result ^=W4;break;} 
switch(key) {    
case('+'):case('='): n++;break;
case('_'):case('-'): n--;break;
case('['):case('{'): r=r-1;break;
case(']'):case('}'): r=r+1;break;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sure your question is much much simpler than this code. The convention in here is to provide a simplified minimal reproducible example where possible as this makes it much easier for people to help, otherwise you will only get help from people with time to wade through your code..

Comment: I am just trying to move 4 ellipses at the same time. But I couldn't. They can only move one at a time so I just need some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not willing to wade through all your constants and switch statements, but the way to solve this problem is to have variables for each possibility. Something like:

```
//direction variables: 1 is up/right, 0 is none, -1 is left/down
int y1 = 0, x1 = 0, y2 = 0, x2 = 0...;

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'w' || key == 'W') y1 = 1;
  if(key == 's' || key == 'S') y1 = -1;
  if(key == 'd' || key == 'D') x1 = 1;
  ... 
}
void keyReleased(){
  if(key == 'w' || key == 'W' || key == 's' || key == 'S') y1 = 0;
  ...
}
void draw(){
  if(y1 == 1) moveOneUp();
  if(y1 == -1) moveOneDown();
  if(y2 == 1) moveTwoUp();
  ...
}
```

do that for all your various possibilities (x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4).